# What is the design of this experiment and how do I analyze it?

Tags: anova, interaction, experiment-design, post-hoc

I carried out an experiment in two locations. For the two locations, the experimental set up was 95 genotypes of a plant in 3 replicates. For each replicate, I had 3 blocks in which the genotypes were randomly distributed. After taking some parameters from both locations, I want to know the performance of the plant genotypes at each location separately and at the same time, the interaction effect of the plant genotypes with the locations. Can I say that my experimental design is lattice design bearing in mind that all the genotypes were not in one block and the 3 blocks in a replicate are not the same size?

Secondly, how do I analyze the data in `R` or SAS? Lastly, what post-hoc test will be best to use? Thank you.

Comment: thank you for using CV. It would be useful if you made the title more descriptive of your problem